# Falta de tradução em "Quero sinalizar esta resposta como..."

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, regressao

Dois dos textos descritivos (*spam* e *rude ou abusivo*) no *modal* que aparece quando sinalizamos uma resposta regrediram:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzido! Só esperar o build.